# Auto adjust decimal depending on length

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to create a function that can set the decimal length based on the length of the whole number.

Lets say I have these numbers:

```
100.12345
10.123456
1.1234567
```

The total length of the whole number should be 5, and the decimal separator should be adjusted so it fits 5 numbers.  This is my desired output:

```
100.12
10.123
1.1234
```

Is there any easy way to accomplish this in C#?

UPDATE: To be more clear in my question on how the conversion should be.

(Current number > Formatted number)

```
100000.222 > 100000
10.222222  > 10.222
1.22       > 1.22
1          > 1
0.2222     > 0.2222
```

Comment: You can start to accomplish this in c# by showing us what you have tried.

Comment: Can the number be greater than 5 digits? (123456?)

Comment: What do you want if the number is 1.0

Comment: How much I miss minimal understanding...

Comment: I think you need to rephrase the question, confusing...

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet because I dont know where to look. Yes, I can do a lot of if else, but that is lame. And I don't know what to search on.. And yes, I tried to search.

Comment: If the number is 1.0, the number is 1.0. What I want is a function that can take a number and cut it down to 5 in length

Comment: @Morten OC, good place to start - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @MortenOC - Google is your friend, and so is MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @O.O I had tried both google and I came across that MSDN page.. But I can't find anything on this. Please enlighten me on what you searched for, or where on that MSDN page you can answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure that this is a good answer, but it seems to work

```
decimal FormatToMaxLength(decimal v, int maxLength)
{

    string s = string.Format("{0}", v);
    if(s.Length > maxLength + 1)
        s = s.Substring(0, maxLength + 1);
    decimal cv;
    decimal.TryParse(s, out cv);
    return cv;
}
```

a revised version that, if the decimal has more numbers in the whole part than requested length preserve the whole part

```
decimal FormatToMaxLength(decimal v, int maxLength)
{
    string s = string.Format("{0}", v);
    string[] parts = s.Split(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator[0]);
    if(parts[0].Length >= maxLength)
        s = parts[0];
    else
        s = s.Substring(0, Math.Min(s.Length, maxLength + 1));
    decimal cv;
    decimal.TryParse(s, out cv);
    return cv;
}
```

Examples tested

```
decimal d = FormatToMaxLength(121.12233m, 5);  // returns 121.12
decimal z = FormatToMaxLength(123456789.12345m, 5);  // returns 123456789
```

Still I am not convinced that converting to a string and then take a subset is a good idea.
Let's see if someone has a better approach or see an obvious solution that I am missing.

Comment: The OP want a string, not a decimal. Just return `s`

Comment: Well that's easy, but there are other problems. What if the string has an integer part with more chars than maxlength... ex : 1234567.9999 ? Should return just 12345?

Comment: @adrianm "The total length of the whole number should be 5".  OP does not state string.

Comment: @Steve thank you! This actually works pretty well with a decimal.  Return type should be decimal. I will update OP to be more clear in my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
static string FormatToMaxLength(decimal d, int maxLength)
    {
        string s = d.ToString();
        s = s.Remove(s.Length - (s.Length - maxLength + 1), s.Length - maxLength - 1);
        return s;
    }
```

this seems to work as well

Comment: Yeah, I have just realized :(